# How to show an object name - of File type - in ListView JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

As I wrote in the topic, I don't know how to do that.
When I add PDF to my `ListView`it shows up to me a file directory, not a name.

I've tried to use a `setCellFactory()` method, but I also don't know how to use it

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListView with custom content in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27438629/listview-with-custom-content-in-javafx)

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, this is what I've looked for, but I still don't understand "what happend" in that method, what are those callbacks and other things doing? Could You explain that to me, I'll be very gratefull :)

Comment: @Daras - If you feel the above linked issue does not answer your question, please edit your question to clarify what exactly is still unclear (If you have made an actual attempt but for some reason it didn't work, please also explain what you tried and paste the relevant code).

Comment: I didn't write any code - I only know, that method will solve my problem - because I don't know how to apply that method as I said above. I'm asking only for an explanation how that method works, what are these callbacks etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `cellFactory` that returns cells that display the item according to your needs:

```
ListView<File> listView = ...
listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<File>() {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(File item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty || item == null) {
            // restore empty look of the cell
            setText("");
        } else {
            // set cell contents based on item
            setText(item.getName());
        }
    } 

});
```

If you adjust this code be aware of the fact that `ListView` may change the item of a `ListCell` to different items and a cell may become empty after a item was associated with it.